# Count elements in array

Tags: java

I am trying to count an element in an array of objects.

```
              long number = Stream.of(jobTitle).count();
              System.out.println("There are " + number + " employees.");
```

What happens is that it will print out the message as many times as many employees have the same job title. Yet "number" stays always 1.

Any guiding would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Stream.of(jobTitle)` is always a stream of one element. `count()` will always return one.

Comment: count of element in array... why you are not using builtin function?

Comment: Hey @AndrewTobilko! Thanks for the feedback. I see now that I will need to use another function.

Comment: @NegiRox Which function would be appropriate here?

Answer (score 4):

```
long number = Stream.of(jobTitle).count();
```

Counts the elements in a **stream** that contains **one** element.

It is not surprising that this operation always ends up with the exact same result.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
List<Whatever> titels = new ArrayList<>();
titels.put(oneEntry);
... print titels.size()
```

Long story short: that statement is nonsensical. What you probably meant was:

```
if (arbetstitel.equalsIgnoreCase(jobCount)){
  g++;
```

or something alikw. Of course `g` is a rather bad name for a counter.

But the real answer here is: step back. **Think** what the problem is you intend to solve, and what the elements are you need to look at. The code you are showing here is simply not making (much) sense. I can't tell you how to fix it, because, as said: it is not clear what you try to achieve here.

A streamish way of counting:

```
long usersWithMatchingTitle = Arrays.stream(employees).filter(e -> e.getJobTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(jobTitleFromUser)).count();
```

Meaning: instead of manually iterating your array, you can turn the whole array into a stream, and then filter/count whatever you want to.

Please note: your code seems to only care about the first 30 elements in that array. If that is really what you want, you will need `...stream(employees).limit(30)...`

Comment: I am trying to count an element in an array of objects is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Béka See my updates then. And as said: seriously look into the way you **name** variables.Also note that you dont necessarily need to use streams. Write simple code that you understand. Dont force streams on you, just because someone tells you "that is easy and cool"

Comment: Many thanks. I am rewriting it now. Using java.util.Arrays. it might work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the stream of command to define a proper Predicate for filter option.

```java
Stream.of(employees).filter(e -> e.getJobTitle().equals(jobTitle)).count();
```